# If $n^2+4n+10$ is a perfect square, then find the possible integer values of $n$.

Tags: quadratics

> If $n^2+4n+10$ is a perfect square, then find the possible integer values of $n$.

I couldn't understand what the question is asking me to do. I could only do one step that would equate it to $k^2$ after that I wasn't able to solve it.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152757/determine-all-integer-values-for-which-2-9-14-is-a-perfect-squar

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** What is $ ( n + 2 ) ^ 2 $?

Comment: Aren't we suppose to scale down the whole into a perfect square or just $(n+2)^2+6$ would be fine?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend: The point is that we're now looking for two perfect squares with a difference of $6$. I don't know which "scale down" you're talking about.

Answer (score 6):

Let $$n^2+4n+10 = k^2$$

Then 
$$k^2-(n+2)^2=6$$

$$\implies k^2=6+(n+2)^2$$

Since $$k^2 \equiv  0~ \text{or} ~1 \pmod4$$

And ,$$6+(n+2)^2  \equiv  2~ \text{or} ~3 \pmod4$$

No solution!

Answer (score 3):

Write $n^2+4n+10 = m^2$. Then $6=m^2-(n+2)^2=(m+n+2)(m-n-2)$.

Now $6=ab=(\pm 1)(\pm 6)$ and $6=(\pm 2)(\pm 3)$ are the only possible factorizations of $6$.

Therefore, we need to solve $m+n+2 = a, m-n-2=b$ for $m,n$.

However, the determinant is $-2$ and we'd need $a,b$ to have the same parity, which never happens. Therefore, there are no integer solutions.

The same argument proves that an integer is the difference of two integer squares iff it is odd or a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Instead of factoring $6$, it is probably just as easy to note that the gaps between _successive_ squares from $9$ onwards are larger than $6$, and clearly none of $0,1,4,9$ have the desired difference.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. right, but my approach leads to solutions in other cases, and a characterization of difference of two squares.

Comment: @lhf We can also use congruences to prove that there is no solution, as I have done in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there are no positive integer solutions because we see from the inequality below that $k^{2}= (n+2)^{2}+6$ lies strictly between two consecutive squares:

$(n+2)^{2} < k^{2}<(n+3)^{2}$

It's easy to manually check that $n=-1,-2,-3,-4$ also fail to make $(n+2)^{2}+6$ a perfect square. The absence of all other negative integer solutions is similarly seen by setting $n=-m,$ for $ m \in \mathbb{N}$ and by noting that $\forall \, m\geq 5$ we have:

$(m-2)^{2}<(m-2)^{2}+6<(m-1)^{2}$

Comment: $n$ isn't given to be positive, this inequality isn't always true.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @JaideepKhare. I extended the same argument to take care of negative integers.

Comment: $m=4$ doesn't satisfy last inequality.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Yes, corrected that. Equality holds for $m=4.5$ and I rounded down by mistake

Answer (score 0):

If $ax^2 + bx + c$ is a perfect square, then there exists only one solution to
$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ as it can then be written as $(x + p)^2$ for some p. This means $b^2 = 4ac$. But in the given equation it is not true ($4^2 != 4*10$), therefore the given equation can never be a perfect square for any real n.

Answer (score 0):

For integers $n,k$  we have $$n^2+4n+10=k^2\implies |k|^2=6+|n+2|^2\implies$$  $$ \implies |k|>|n+2|\implies |k|\geq 1+|n+2|\implies$$  $$\implies 6=|k|^2-|n+2|^2\geq (1+|n+2|)^2-|n+2|^2=1+2|n+2|\implies$$  $$ \implies 6\geq 1+2|n+2|\implies 5\geq 2|n+2|\implies$$  $$\implies 2+\frac {1}{2}\geq |n+2|\implies 2\geq |n+2|\implies$$ $$ \implies |n+2| \in \{0,1,2\} \implies  |n+2|^2\in \{0,1,4\}\implies$$ $$\implies|k|^2=6+|n+2|^2\in \{6,7,10\}\implies 1=0.$$